# Changing the value of a variable inside of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, coding-efficiency

I am working in C++ and I have a function that has too many parameters and I would like to shorten the amount of parameters need to pass into the function.

Specifically, I have a function `foo` which takes in several `int`s and I would like to place them in a vector (or some other type, this is just the first type of 'container' I thought of) which I can use to shorten the number of parameters while in effect passing in the variables inside of the vector by reference, not by value.

For example, I want to have

```
<SomeClass> foo(vector<int>& vec) {
    vec.at(0) = 10;
    vec.at(2) = 7;
    ....
    return someClassObj;
}
```

where a vector of integer parameters, `parameter_vec = {x, y, z}`, would be passed into `foo`.

I want to know how I can write this function so that the corresponding variable  `x`  at `parameter_vec.at(0)` has actually changed the parameter `x` to 10 instead of just changing the value of `parameter_vec.at(0)` to 10 inside of `parameter_vec` after passing it through `foo`.

If this idea is just weird, unclear, overcomplicated, or a bit stupid, let me know. I can try to clarify and I am open to suggestions on ways to shorten the list of parameters which have to be passed into a function through other methods. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question appears to be missing the *question* part of the question, which is often the most important part of the question.

Comment: @Eljay is it more clear now?

Answer (score 2):

One of approaches is the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

void f( std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<int>> lst )
{
    auto it = std::begin( lst );
    
    ( it++ )->get() = 10;
    ( it++ )->get() = 7;
    it->get() = 4;
}

int main() 
{
    int x, y , z;
    
    f( { x, y, z } );
    
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    std::cout << "y = " << y << '\n';
    std::cout << "z = " << z << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 10
y = 7
z = 4
```

Comment: agh, i wish i understood this. thank you, though

Comment: (1) std::reference_wrapper creates a reference from the thing, (2) std::initializer_list allows you to use the {x, y, z} notation at the call site.

Comment: im assuming that `it` is almost like a pointer to the first element in the initializer list? and then you traverse the list by incrementing the `it` thing?

Comment: _"... almost like a pointer ..."_ - this seems like an apposite moment to learn about iterators. They are indeed a generalization of pointers, and should be covered in any decent book for beginners (or the old SGI STL [documentation](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/Iterators.html) for motivation and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) for current detail).

Answer (score 1):

Having to remember which element of `std::vector<int>` does what is a pain, and vulnerable to error.

Consider using a `struct` so that the elements can be named more appropriately:

```
struct Foo
{
    int& something;
    int& something_else;
};
```

If your function takes a `const Foo&` as a parameter, you can even call the function using the initialiser-list syntax `{x, y}` to assign `x` to `something`, and `y` to `something_else`. These assignments are by reference, not by value.

Example use:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int& something;
    int& something_else;
};

void foo(const Foo& f)
{
    f.something = 1;
    f.something_else = 2;
}

int main() {
    int x, y;
    foo({x, y});
    std::cout << x << " " << y; // Output is 1 and 2.
}
```

Comment: Hmm. If I am wanted to pass the parameters by reference originally, would this have the same effect? Just want to pay caution to your note.

Comment: @CSquared: Fixed it. It carries the advantage of having nice names for the parameters in `foo`, but Vlad's answer has an elegance to it.

Comment: I'm way to new to programming to see it the elegance in it yet. not sure if it matters, but all of my functions are in a Class. can i define structs inside of classes, or should i define this outside of the class entirely?

Comment: @CSquared You can indeed define classes within classes. Note that a `struct` is the same as a `class` in C++, the chief difference being that in a `struct` all members and functions are `public` by default, rather than `private`. (You can define a `class` within a function too, which is how we used to write lambda functions before they became part of the language proper.)